# Python ftplib add new line to txt file during upload file to FTP server

Tags: python, ftplib

I use following code to upload txt files in ASCII mode to FTP server

```
import glob
import os
import hashlib
from ftplib import FTP 

server = '1.1.1.1'
login = 'user'
password = 'password'
path = './test_files/'
file_mask = '*.txt'

def upload_to_ftp(srv, uname, pwd, file_name):
    ftp = FTP(srv, uname, pwd)    
    ftp.cwd('Pava')    
    file = open(path+file_name, 'rb')
    ftp.storlines('STOR '+file_name, file)
    size = ftp.size(file_name)           
    ftp.close()
    file.close()
    print (size)

def local_size_check(file_name):
    file_size = os.stat(path+file_name)
    print (file_size.st_size)


file_to_upload = glob.glob1(path, file_mask)
for i in file_to_upload:
    try:
        os.rename(path+i, path+i)
    except OSError as e:
        print ('Access-error on file ' + i + ' ! \n' + str(e))
    else:
        upload_to_ftp(server, login, password, i)
        local_size_check(i)
```

The output of this two functions is:
78
76
Then i have dowloaded file from ftp and found that during transfering by FTP was added new line at the end of file.
[local and remote file screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HP3y.png)

[image]

Please help to solve this problem.
BTW if use binary mode new line do not add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should upload your file in binary mode so that it will not be subject to the server's text interpretation.

Change:

```
ftp.storlines('STOR '+file_name, file)
```

to:

```
ftp.storbinary('STOR '+file_name, file)
```